# condicionales if en handlebars

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, handlebars

Buenas a todos me pregunto si posible hacer algo como esto?

```
{{#each bebidas_var}}
{{#if nombre == "sin bebida sin cubiertos"}}
<h1>ok</h1>
{{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

ya lo intente la verdad no creo que sea posible pero quiero saber si hay alternativas.
gracias :)

Comment: creo que te falta utilizar el símbolo `#` antes del `if`

Comment: corregido pero no funciona aun

Comment: Espero esto te pueda ayudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional#16315366

Comment: Modifique el enlace para que des con la segunda respuesta mas fácilmente ;)